# PHP spreadsheet not working when i use objects

Tags: php, excel

im trying to use phpspreadsheet to save some data from my db to an excel file. The problem is: when i create my sql object, my excel document just the format is not valid. When i delete the object, file opens normally. if i comment the line $psql = new PSql(); it may works fine.

```
require_once("funcoes/Psql.php");
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$psql = new PSql();
$dados = $psql->getUltimoRegistro($_SESSION["contrato"]);
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A1', "Contrato")
            ->setCellValue('B1', "Código")
            ->setCellValue('C1', "Estatstica")
            ->setCellValue('D1', "Infração");

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx"');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: I assume the statement new PSql is generating an error or warning. Since you're saving ALL output to the file that warning will be added to the file and thus making it invalid. To fix the problem, find out why new PSql() is giving you an error. For example create a file with only psql, without all the excel stuff

Comment: session wasnt started, that was the issue.